# Fill an ncurses window with a color

Tags: c, ncurses

I only have a basic knowledge of ncurses, and I was unable to find an answer to this question in the man pages.

When you set the foreground and background color for a window, is there a way to fill the whole window with the background color?

Comment: Set the background colour to be the same as the foreground? Or fill the window with spaces?

Comment: I mean some sort of routine that is equivalent to manually filling a window with spaces.

Answer (score 44):

Please try `bkgd`, or `wbkgd` for specifying a window.

First you have to enable color support with `start_color()`.

And then define color pair.
Example:`init_pair(1,COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_RED)`

The order is `pair_number`, `foreground`, `background`

Finally, set colors: `wbkgd(WindowName, COLOR_PAIR(1))`.

Comment: WARNING! Don't forget to use COLOR_PAIR(n) and not simply n. I did and spent 2 days trying to figure out why ncurses was not displaying the spaces in my output.
(That should contain the search terms so the next poor soul who does the same thing can figure it out faster!)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `wbkgd(stdscr, COLOR_PAIR(1))` to change the main window color.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to go back to normal background:

By default, `start_color` imposes using the first black in your color scheme - 0. Named also `COLOR_BLACK`.

To change that, call `use_default_colors()` to have ncurses use the default background instead.